# Different languages for month in Date

Tags: civimail

I have a French Drupal 7.67 /Civicrm 5.19.3 site with the right settings for the localization. Every strings that are translated in transifex appear translated. In the admin, the months are translated to French:

[image: civicrm/admin/setting/date?action=reset=1]

but in any email send, they still show in English:

[image: email]

Do I have to configure something else outside of `civicrm/admin/setting/date?action=reset=1`?

regards
Guillaume

Comment: Are you using specific user-driven message template to send email? Or from custom message template ?

Comment: custom message template

Comment: So it depends upon how you trying to print the dates.

Comment: I'm using the token {latestcurrentmembership.end_date} in the html code. Is there an other way to do so?

Comment: Try resaving the localization settings again.

Comment: I still have this uncomfortable issue especially when I create PDF letters for contacts with a mix of English and French.